# Context parameter (in context receivers functionality) not showing via reflection

Tags: kotlin, reflection, kotlin-context-receivers

Via reflection, I need to distinguish between a method with a context and a method without a context (Kotlin 1.8.0).

Let's say we have following dummy context and a class with two functions - one with the context, second without.

```
  class Context(val a: Int)

  class Foo {
    context (Context)
    fun bar() = a
    
    fun baz() = 1
  }
```

In runtime, we don't know which method is which, so let's try to distinguish them via reflection.

```
  val foo = Foo()

  val barMethod = foo::class.memberFunctions.first { it.name == "bar" }
  println("barMethod has ${barMethod.parameters.size} parameter(s)")

  val bazMethod = foo::class.memberFunctions.first { it.name == "baz" }
  println("bazMethod has ${bazMethod.parameters.size} parameter(s)")
```

The problem is, both return they have 1 parameter (and they are identical in all other public properties). But obviously, when called, `bar` will fail if provided only one parameter. If called as expected, it works.

```
  // println(barMethod.call(foo))        -- fails
  println(bazMethod.call(foo))

  println(barMethod.call(foo, Context(6))
```

When debugging, I found, there actually is an internal property `descriptor` on barMethod (KCallableImpl) which contains `contextReceiverParameters` property correctly showing 1 for barMethod and 0 for bazMethod. But it's not accessible.

Any idea, if there's any supported way of retrieving information about context receivers via reflection, or it simply hasn't been implemented yet?

Answer (score 0):

First, define the annotation class:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
annotation class WithContext
```

Then, annotate the functions that have a context receiver with this annotation:

```
class Context(val a: Int)

class Foo {
    context (Context)
    
    @WithContext
    fun bar() = a
    
    fun baz() = 1
}
```

Now you can use the following code to check if a function has a context receiver:

```
val foo = Foo()

val barMethod = foo::class.memberFunctions.first { it.name == "bar" }
val hasBarContext = barMethod.annotations.any { it is WithContext }
println("barMethod has context: $hasBarContext")

val bazMethod = foo::class.memberFunctions.first { it.name == "baz" }
val hasBazContext = bazMethod.annotations.any { it is WithContext }
println("bazMethod has context: $hasBazContext")
```

This will output:

```
barMethod has context: true
bazMethod has context: false
```

Keep in mind that this approach relies on manually adding the **@WithContext** annotation to the functions with context receivers. There might be a more direct way to access the context receiver parameters in future Kotlin versions when the feature becomes stable and the reflection